# jquery submit with function does not work on the on-click button event binded to an object

Tags: jquery, jbox

Using the normal `$(selector).submit()`, but when I added a function inside the submit method it does not execute the codes inside.

Here is the snippet of the code:

```js
onCreated: function() {
    this.footer = jQuery('<div class="jBox-footer"/>');
    this.submitButton = jQuery('<button class="jBox-btn jBox-btn-lg jBox-btn-save btn btn-primary btn-md"/>')
      .html("Login <i class='fa fa-sign-in'></i>").appendTo(this.footer);
    this.footer.appendTo(this.container);
  },
  onOpen: function() {
    this.submitButton.off('click.jBox-Modal' + this.id).on('click.jBox-Modal' + this.id, function() {

      $("#bulk-login").submit(function(e) {
        alert('test');
      });

    }).bind(this);
  }
```

I'm not sure what causes the problem why it's not executing the inner code for the sumbit. Could anyone tell me what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the button type to submit in order for it to trigger a submit event on your bulk-login form:

```js
this.submitButton = jQuery('<button type="submit" class="jBox-btn jBox-btn-lg jBox-btn-save btn btn-primary btn-md"/>')
      .html("Login <i class='fa fa-sign-in'></i>").appendTo(this.footer);
```

Comment: @robertpeter07 If your submit button is outside of your form, you will need to trigger the submit on the button click: 

    this.submitButton.click(function(){  $('#bulk-login').submit();});